# Not able to access websites when Charles Proxy is opened (Windows 10)

Tags: http, https, proxy, charles-proxy

I downloaded the app Charles Proxy, I added the certificate and I can confirm that the Charles certificate is in my certlm (Certificate Manager) in the "Trusted Root Certification" folder, I had also enabled SSL Proxying to include this location: "*:443" which I believe means that I want to see all data coming in.

I'm not sure what the problem is, but whenever I open up Charles Proxy, it doesn't allow me to access any websites, all the data coming in Charles is coming in as status: "Blocked"

I'm using Windows 10 if that helps. I didn't have this issue on MacOS, Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here was the solution to my problem:

First quit Charles. Then go to the Internet Options in your Control Panel. Go to the Connections tab. Click on the LAN Settings. You’ll see a Proxy panel. Uncheck the Use a Proxy checkbox. Click OK until you’ve closed the Internet Options.

Then opened up Charles Log, go to Tools -> Allow List and make sure "Enable Allow List" is unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check Windows proxy settings as your applications are most probably trying to communicate on a wrong IP/port proxy address matching.

Open **cmd** *(Windows+R, cmd, Enter)*.
Execute:

```
rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL inetcpl.cpl,,4
```

Click on **LAN settings**, then check **Use a proxy server for your LAN**.

[image]

Click **Advanced** button near `Address` and `Port` labels.

Define your **addresses** and **ports** here. I once had a task that required me to check all incoming and outgoing HTTP/HTTPS connections from my machine, so I set on HTTP field the address **127.0.0.1** with port **8888** and checked the option "Use the same proxy server for all protocols". If you want a finer control, you leave this option unchecked set different ports to handle **FTP** and **Socks** connections. *Those ports are used by Charles. Check those settings in Charles Proxy as well!*

[image]

Click **Ok**, then click **Ok** again.

On Charles, in **Proxy-Proxy settings**, make sure the port numbers are the same for the relative protocols as you set up before in the Windows proxy page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I personally have never used Charles on a Windows machine but it sounds like your browser isn't configured to run through the proxy.  Firefox use to have an add-on for Charles but now you have to manually enter the proxy ip to intercept the data.  I'm not sure if you can use any other browsers on Windows with Charles, but use Firefox and go to Preferences > Network Settings > Manual Proxy Configuration and add your machine's ip address and the default Charles port 8888.  Also make sure to check the checkbox to allow HTTPS.  Save these changes and you should be good to go.

Comment: Even though I primarily use Chrome for development, I'm giving this a try to see if that is the issue on FireFox. 

I set a manual proxy, and when accessing a site like google.com, i'm getting the following:

`
 Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue

www.google.com is most likely a safe site, but a secure connection could not be established. This issue is caused by Charles Proxy CA

www.google.com has a security policy called HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS), which means that Firefox can only connect to it securely. You can’t add an exception to visit this site.`

Comment: HSTS is a technology that allows a website to say to the browser "Require all future requests within X time to use the same certificate authority." (Google is their own CA so I'm using Twitter for clarity). twitter.com uses DigiCert as their CA. twitter uses HSTS to tell your browser to expect DigiCert next time too, but instead you get the CA you created for Charles, so you get the warning. Browsers also ship with a pre-loaded list of CAs for major websites. Google for how to disable HSTS to see workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Windows machine to try any of this out, but I've always found the documentation helpful.

There may be something that you've overlooked in the [configuration](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/browser-and-system-configuration/), [ssl proxying](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/ssl-proxying/) or [ssl certificates](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/) sections.

Comment: I followed their instruction in the documentation which I outlined in my original post, I had also double-checked those links to see if I was missing something but doesn't look like it.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Windows Proxy" under Proxy tab or you can use shortcut "Ctrl+Shift+P"